# Windows 10 terminal: Is it possible to save ssh password?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, terminal

My question is about the new windows 10 terminal

At work, I SSH to several servers daily, centos 6 and centos 7, I need to save ssh password, like mobaxterm

I can't create ssh keys, because I have far too many servers, windows doesn't have `ssh-copy-id` so it would take so much time to setup the ssh keys on all the servers I manage. And sometimes the keys don't work because of permission issue or something, I end up being locked out. I tried doing that 3 weeks ago, that happened, I don't want to take any risks on old servers running in production.

I need something like [sshpass](https://askubuntu.com/a/85655/23239), but you can't specify the port in `sshpass`, and all the production servers have ssh running on ports different that port 22, so `sshpass` is useless for me

Comment: See [here](https://www.chrisjhart.com/Windows-10-ssh-copy-id/#:~:text=%20Windows%2010%20OpenSSH%20Equivalent%20of%20%22ssh-copy-id%22%20,Linux%20Device.%20Finally%2C%20verify%20that%20you...%20More%20), using Windows Terminal offers ssh-kegen